# Placing a .pdf file in the center with \multirow

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, positioning

The following is my code

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\scalebox{0.9}{\begin{tabular}{c|c|cc}

 \emph{}&\emph{a}&\emph{b}&\emph{c}\\
 \hline
\rotatebox{90}{text}&\multirow{2}{*}{
                       \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]      {a.pdf}} &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{b.pdf} &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{c.pdf}\
   \rotatebox{90}{text}&  &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{a1.pdf} &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{b1.pdf}\\
\end{tabular} 
}
\caption[]
     {}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

I 'm trying to place a.pdf in the central part of the first column (currently, it's placed in the second row). In addition, I would like to have a line between the two rows, but the line should not go into a.pdf. Could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `\multirow`:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|cc}
&\emph{a}&\emph{b}&\emph{c}\\
\hline
\rotatebox{90}{text}&
  \smash{\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{a.pdf}}} &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{b.pdf} &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{c.pdf}\\
   \rotatebox{90}{text}&  &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{a1.pdf} &
   \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{b1.pdf}\\
\end{tabular}
```